# Why are the specs reversed in the following piece of code for multi-sorting on a bunch of object attributes?

Tags: python, sorting

The following function takes a tuple of (attribute, reverse_order) and sorts the given list xs on each one of them. Why is there reversed being used here?

```
def multisort(xs, specs):
    for key, reverse in reversed(specs):
        xs.sort(key=attrgetter(key), reverse=reverse)
    return xs
```

Documentation link : https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained in the example that motivates the `multisort` function:

> This wonderful property lets you build complex sorts in a series of
> sorting steps. For example, to sort the student data by descending
> *grade* and then ascending *age*, do the *age* sort first and then sort
> again using *grade*:
>
> ```
> >>> s = sorted(student_objects, key=attrgetter('age'))     # sort on secondary key 
> >>> sorted(s, key=attrgetter('grade'), reverse=True)       # now sort on primary key, descending
> [('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
> ```

For the sorting logic to be correct, you need to sort by the secondary key first and by the primary key last.

The reason for reversing the sort keys inside the `multisort` function is to be able **to write them in a more intuitive order (primary, secondary)** when *calling* the function.

---

<sub>I think the particular example that is given in the linked documentation is not useful to demonstrate *why* the result would be wrong if the two sorting passes where done in the non-reversed order, but I can't think of a better one right now.</sub>